# Any straight-forward way to animate the transition from Portrait to Landscape in Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I wish there were some clear, straight way to animate the transition of an app from landscape to portrait, like the 1st party apps do.

I googled, I binged but I can't find any straight answers, not even a "no can do".

Comment: And you never even attempted to do anything I take it?

Comment: Well I thought I could handle the orientation-changed event but I hoped and searched for a behavior or other xaml-based solution..

Comment: I'll get to test the solution when I get home where I have Win8 and validate the first (chronologically) answer that fits my need. Thank you for your effort!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [this article](http://mobileworld.appamundi.com/blogs/andywigley/archive/2010/11/23/windows-phone-7-page-orientation-change-animations.aspx) is what you search.
 It says about Windows Phone 7, but actions described in it are applicable for WP8.
Just plug [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/) via NuGet or manually.

Comment: I must have discarded it because it said "7"... but I'm reading it right now!

Comment: ".. not much has been said about the Orientation change transitions .." true.

Answer (score 1):

@lumen is correct the Phone Toolkit (OS from Microsoft) is a great way to do it.

Read Andy Wigley's post on how to do it (yes the documentation on the Phone codeplex page is a bit scare adn is mostly blogged about by the contributors)

http://mobileworld.appamundi.com/blogs/andywigley/archive/2010/11/23/windows-phone-7-page-orientation-change-animations.aspx

Alternatively if you have the Telerik Controls, you can just implement their Transition page control in pretty much the same way but you will have even greater control for how that looks.

Hope this helps